# Apache Ignite: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character

Tags: ignite

Getting below error message, can someone please help?

```
Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "Book/1"; SQL statement:
SELECT KEY, AFFINITYKEY, _VAL FROM "test-client_null_cache4"."EVENTDATA"  WHERE AFFINITYKEY = 'Book/1' [90004-197]
```

I have key as custom object as below:

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class IgniteKey<P> {
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private final String key;

  @AffinityKeyMapped
  @QuerySqlField
  private final P bookId;

  public IgniteKey(String key, P bookId) {
    this.key = key;
    this.bookId = bookId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing 'Book/1' with double quotes or escape characters explicitly using "\"

Comment: Did not worked. I changed P to String and it worked.